# mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to show attached documents to users and as attachments are mostly files not photos such as `zip` `pdf` `docx` i want to show static images regarding to type of those attachments but i get this error

```
mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments
```

> Note: I am using Laravel PHP Framework and this validation is
>   happening in blade template

`Code`

```
@if(mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file == 'application/zip'))

    <img src="{{url('img')}}/zip.jpg" alt="zip file" class="img-fluid">

@elseif(mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file == 'application/pdf'))

    <img src="{{url('img')}}/pdf.jpg" alt="pdf file" class="img-fluid">

@elseif(mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file == 'application/msword'))

    <img src="{{url('img')}}/docx.png" alt="docx file" class="img-fluid">

@elseif(mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file == 'image/jpeg'))

    <img src="{{url('img')}}/jpeg.png" alt="jpeg file" class="img-fluid">

@elseif(mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file == 'image/png'))

    <img src="{{url('img')}}/png.png" alt="png file" class="img-fluid">

@else

    <img src="{{url('img')}}/unknown.png" alt="unknown file" class="img-fluid">

@endif
```

PS: If I use this code for instance

```
{{dd(mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file) )}}
```

I will get

```
"application/zip"
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Wrong alignment of the string comparison in the `if`. Move it outside the function call.

Comment: @Namoshek you're right my bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if(mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file == 'application/zip'))
```

you should use this (look at  parentheses):
Your code is returning bool not a string

```
@if(mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file) == 'application/zip')
```

Comment: Oops! my bad :)  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
mime_content_type('images/'.$document->file   ==   'application/zip')
```

You probably don't want to be doing an equality check on those 2 strings in the function call.

```
'images/'.$document->file   ==   'application/zip'

false
```

So you are basically taking the long way to write:

```
@if (mime_content_type(false))
```